# resize field and resize back outside click

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and I kinda don't get around this. So I have a searchbox (.search) which I want to resize when it's clicked. That does work, the searchfield get's "bigger". But, when I click outside the searchfield I want it to grow back again. I tried doing it with a "body"-click-method. But it doesn't work.

So here's my code:

```
$(function() {
$('.search').click(function() {
    $('.search').css('width', '450px');
});});
```

Another question: How can I combine this change with an animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.search').focus(function() {
     $('.search').css('width', '450px');
});
$('.search').blur(function() {
     $('.search').css('width', 'auto');
});
```

If you want to animate the width change you can do this:

```
$('.search').focus(function() {
     $('.search').animate({width: '450px'});
});
$('.search').blur(function() {
     $('.search').animate({width: '150px'});
});
```

Otherwise if you wish to animate another object you can do this:

```
$('.search').focus(function() {
     $('.search').css('width', '450px');
     $('#id_to_animate').animate({width: '200px'});
});
$('.search').blur(function() {
     $('.search').css('width', '150px');
     $('#id_to_animate').animate({width: '100px'});
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. :)

Now, the only other question I have so far is: can I put to the resizing?

Comment: Could you expand your question a bit, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ is the documentation page for animate in JQuery. $('.search').animate({width: '450px'}, 3000, 'linear', function() {}); The 3000 corresponds to the time that the animation will take to complete, 'linear' corresponds to the type of easing (you can get the jquery easing plugin to get like 30 different types of easing), and 'function(){}' corresponds to a custom function that you can create that will run at the end of the animation. Here is the link to the JQuery easing plugin http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery blur event to resize the element back down after it loses focus:

http://api.jquery.com/blur